# How to create a sort function that would automatically sort new incoming data

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I linked a form to google spreadsheets, so now all the responses on that form are linked, and they automatically are added as plain data in the spreadsheet. One of the columns is date-data, on column B, but the responses are added to the spreadsheets as data in ascending order of submission, so I wanted to know how to create a sort function that would automatically sort new incoming data in descending order according to Column B.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try **Insert > New sheet** and this formula in cell A1 of the new sheet:

`=query('Form Responses 1'!A1:A, "order by B desc", 1)`

Alternatively, if you want to sort the `Form Responses 1` sheet *in place*, it is better to use [filter views](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681) to sort the sheet instead of using **Data > Sort**. A filter view definition can be saved and easily re-activated.

For additional ease of use, you can insert links in the frozen section of the sheet to easily switch between filter views, instead of having to go to **Data > Filter views** to switch. See the [Filter views example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ME5b4J6fQa8RRainxGtQkwTKFCg96N8_k6kCe8ABNyk/edit#gid=2048818001&fvid=336145647) spreadsheet for an illustration.